# How to fix no network

Tags: 14.04, networking, compatibility

What does it mean when it says 14.04 LTS ubuntu they system network is not compatible with is version and how can it be fixed

Comment: What is the output of `ip a` ?

Comment: I'm using a Ethernet cable

Comment: Yes so? What's the output of the command? And show the picture of that error

Comment: It doesn't tell me or show cuz it doesn't have networking icon or net work manager

Comment: Not can I upload anything 2 show

Comment: It won't let me upload pic

Comment: Just open a terminal and type `ip a` and `ping google.com`. Mostly the second command won't give out any output but do try it out. Did you try it out with any other ethernet connection?

Comment: You know updating is free? 14.04 is EOL in 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I found something here that might help you 
[link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324504)!

I am suggesting you to reinstall ubuntu and the drivers without deleting the files.